# Upstart - make "reload" behave like "restart"

Tags: upstart, daemon

I have a daemon process that doesn't respond to `SIGHUP` sent when running `reload`.

It runs under an unprivileged user, and I can't restart it without `sudo` privileges.

Is there a way to make `reload` to behave the same as `restart`, by changing the task configuration, so I can run it as an unprivileged user?

I'm using Upstart 1.5 on Ubuntu 12.04.